# Storing value in var from form submission with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have looked at many answers and none seem to fit the issue.  I have a simple search box and submit button, and want to store the value of the input field in a variable.  It seems to store at first, then disappears. Code:

### **JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('form').submit(function(){
        var input = $('#search').val();
        $('p').append(input);
    });
});
```

---

**HTML**

```
 <form>
    <input id='search' class='form-control' type='text' name='search'>
    <input id='submit' type='submit' value='Submit' class='btn btn-lg btn-primary'>
 </form>
 <p></p>
```

The variable will display for a second and disappear, presumably when the search box becomes empty again.

Answer (score 3):

The reason this happens is because when you submit a form the browser will send a new HTTP request to the server and reload your page. You could prevent this behavior by returning `false` from the submit handler:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var input = $('#search').val();
    $('p').append(input);
    return false;
});
```

or alternatively:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var input = $('#search').val();
    $('p').append(input);
});
```

This will prevent the page from reloading and the changes you did to the DOM will remain.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('form').submit(function(){
        var input = $('#search').val();
        $('p').append(input);
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input id='search' class='form-control' type='text' name='search'>
    <input id='submit' type='submit' value='Submit' class='btn btn-lg btn-primary'>
 </form>
 <p></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting result you can do something like this

**In HTML code**

```
<form action="" method="get" id="search_form">
    <input id='search' class='form-control' type='text' name='search'>
    <input id='submit' type='submit' value='Submit' class='btn btn-lg btn-primary'>
 </form>
 <p></p>
<div id="search_result"></div>
```

**in Javascript code**

```
$('#search_form').submit(function(){
    var input = $('#search').val();
    $('p').text(input);
    $("#search_result").load($(this).attr("action")+ " #search_result", function(){
        alert("result loaded for "+ input)
    })
    return false;
});
```